# Percentage of volume of object above water

Tags: physics

I'm having difficulty proving that the percentage of the volume of an object above the surface of a liquid is

$$\frac{100(p_f-p_o)}{p_f}$$

given that buoyant force exerted by the liquid on the object is

$$F=p_fg\int_{-h}^0A(y)dy$$

where $A(y)$ is the cross sectional area of the object and the weight of the object is

$$W=p_og\int_{-h}^{L-h}A(y)dy$$

where $L$ is the height of the object and $h$ is the distance the object is submerged into the liquid.

I tried comparing the ratio of two volume of revolution integrals but didn't manage to get anywhere. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Let $V$ be the volume of the object.
Let $V'$ be the volume of water dispaced.

% of the volume above the water $\frac {V-V'}{V}$

$\rho_0$ is the density of the object
$\rho_f$ is the density of water.

the weight of the object = the weight of the water displaced

$\rho_0 V = \rho_f V'\\
V' = \frac{\rho_0}{\rho_f} V$

Substituting into what we have above:

$1-\frac{\rho_0}{\rho_f} = \frac{\rho_f-\rho_0}{\rho_f}$

Answer (score 0):

Using Archimedes principle we have
$$
F = W
$$
or using the equations provided
$$
p_fg\int_{-h}^0A(y)dy = p_og\int_{-h}^{L-h}A(y)dy
$$
we can remove $g$ from both sides
$$
p_f\int_{-h}^0A(y)dy = p_o\int_{-h}^{L-h}A(y)dy
$$
The integral on the right hand side is the total Volume of the object.
$$
p_f\int_{-h}^0A(y)dy = p_oV_{\text{Total}}
$$
whilst the left hand side is
$$
p_f\int_{-h}^0A(y)dy = p_f\int_{-h}^{L-h}A(y)dy  - p_f\int_{0}^{L-h}A(y)dy = p_fV_{\text{total}} -p_f\int_{0}^{L-h}A(y)dy 
$$
the integral
$$
\int_{0}^{L-h}A(y)dy 
$$
is the volume above the water, $V_{\text{above water}}$.
This means we have
$$
p_f\int_{-h}^0A(y)dy  = p_fV_{\text{total}}-p_fV_{\text{above water}} = p_oV_{\text{Total}}
$$
we can now re-arrange to obtain
$$
p_fV_{\text{above water}} = p_fV_{\text{total}}-p_oV_{\text{Total}} = (p_f - p_0)V_{\text{Total}}
$$
or
$$
\frac{V_{\text{above water}} }{V_{\text{Total}}} = \frac{p_f-p_0}{p_f}
$$
or in terms of percentage you can multiply by $100$.